# How to add a 3D parallax effect wallpaper in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, android-wallpaper

I'm building a flutter wallpaper application and one of the requirements is to add a 3d Parallax image as a wallpaper and also add it in the app. I'm using firebase at the backend and the admin panel is in react. The images are uploaded via admin panel and then fetched to display in app via firebase SDK with flutter. Now I want to add 3D parallax images via admin panel and then set them as wallpaper using the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

There is two different way can reach your amazing goal:

1. Using package [async_wallpaper](https://pub.dev/packages/async_wallpaper) that can add your animation as mp4 (maybe you have to convert your file to mp4) and also all other image formats (png, jpeg, etc), but unfortunately not working on IOS devices (I search across all packages there is alternative in IOS) ️.
2. Use media gallery extension packages like [media_extension](https://pub.dev/packages/media_extension),
   which allows the user to open the image to the default wallpaper manager in Android, IOS so can user then change the background image as the docs said.